# Ruby parsing error

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have the following recipe for Chef:

```
def prestashop_deployDatabase (username)
    sql_path = '/tmp/prestashop_create_tables.sql'

    template sql_path do
        source "prestashop152.sql.erb"
        owner "root"
        group node['mysql']['root_group']
        mode "0600"
        variables(
            :username => #{username}
        )
        action :create
    end
end
```

For some reason; it cannot understand the 'username' argument i'm passing.

PS: I'm a Ruby n00b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#{username}` is a comment in ruby. You should write `"#{username}"`, or better in this case, just `username`.

Comment: Not entirely equivalent, `username.to_s` in case you get weird errors.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby:

- `#` in **code** starts a one-line comment
- `#{}` in a **string** starts interpolation - everything in the braces will be interpreted as ruby code.

Since you're using `#` in code here, it comments out the rest of the line `{username}`, so in effect your code says this:

```
variables(
  :username =>
)
```

which will give you a syntax error.